# Routing based on country

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angularjs-routing

I am trying to display unique pages based on country. I am referring to the Nike website.
https://www.nike.com/sg/en_gb/. Here the user has the option to select a region/country:

How to implement using Routing Param instead of the path. I would like to implement using the Routing params or a better solution if any.

**View**

```
<body ng-controller="CountryController">
    <form>
      <select name="naver" id="naver" ng-model="route.selectedRoute" ng-change="RedirecttoCountry(route.selectedRoute)">
        <option value="/" >Home</option>
        <option value="/US">US</option>
        <option value="/UK">UK</option>
        <option value="/India">India</option>
      </select>
    </form>
    <div ng-view=""></div>
```

I have separate htmls for each country.

**Controller**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: "US.html",
            controller: 'CountryController'
        })
        .when('/UK', {
            templateUrl: "UK.html",
            controller: 'CountryController'
        })
        .when('/India', {
            templateUrl: "India.html",
            controller: 'CountryController'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});

app.controller('CountryController', function($scope, $location){
    $scope.RedirecttoCountry = function( path ){
        $location.path(path);
    }
});
```

Comment: If i am correct you can add a param by doing `/:country`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you need single route dynamically handling all countries, in that you could use `templateUrl` as function with `:country` defined as parameter.

```
.when('/:country', {
    templateUrl: function(params){
        return (params.country || 'US')+'.html';
    },
    controller: 'CountryController'
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be working fine. Just make sure you have included all the dependencies and closed all your HTML tags properly.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: "main.html",
        controller: 'CountryController'
    }).when('/:country', {
        templateUrl: function(params) {
            return (params.country) + '.html';
        },
        controller: 'CountryController'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
});
app.controller('CountryController', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.RedirecttoCountry = function(path) {
        $location.path(path);
    }
});
```

**Working Plunker using params**: https://plnkr.co/edit/hFLCyGgo91GwQhpagvAz?p=preview

Comment: the link is not updated i believe, i am not seeing the params

Answer (score 1):

`templateUrl` can be a function of the parameters, for ex.:

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/:country', {
    templateUrl: function(params) {
      return params.country + '.html';
    }
  })
  .when('/', {
    template: 'default'
  })
  .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
```

See:
https://plnkr.co/edit/rNQutPGZ5b4B0NK5g4Wz?p=preview